# How to use controllers and model code of theme used as plugin in Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am new to cakephp, and started working on ecommerce site. Created plugin for theme Admin panel, the structure of admin panel theme plugin is as follows:

> plugins/admin_theme/

```
|_ config
|_ src 
    |_ Controller
        |_AppController.php
    |_ Template
        |_Layout
          |_default.ctp
|_ tests 
|_ webroot
```

Now the confusion is where should i put my controller and model for AdminPanel theme, in the main src folder if i put all my code it will be mixed with my other application code, and the second thing i want to create other theme for my 
main application, what is the correct way to use multiple plugin and the most important where to put the coding part (i.e. controllers and models) if i want to use two theme.

Comment: I'm scared when people who can't find or aren't willing to read documentation want to create applications that involve money... Read the manual? It covers everything you ask for: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html & https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/themes.html

Comment: @burzum i have read it https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/themes.html but it does not contains what i have asked above

Comment: @burzum http://findnerd.com/list/view/Integrate-theme-in-Cakephp-3-x/28722/ but it does'nt covered coding parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to create new folder named "plugins" in your root folder. Then as suggested in document https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/themes.html create folder structure like inside plugins dir /src/Template.

And in your controller add below line in beforeRender() method to set theme:

```
// For CakePHP before 3.1
public $theme = 'Modern';
// For CakePHP before 3.5
$this->viewBuilder()->theme('Modern');
// For CakePHP after 3.5
$this->viewBuilder()->setTheme('Modern');
```

For in depth information please refer https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/themes.html.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if i'm using 2 plugins of theme then (one for the user end and the other admin panel) the business logic of both will be in respective plugins folder or all coding in one place i.e. root controller folder within src. That i want to clear.

Comment: As I mentioned you can call any theme admin and user conditionally by viewBuiler in your controller, you can separate admin and user end by prefix if you like.

Comment: I have created plugin but it is being called but i cannot understand what is the use of Model,Controller inside plugin folder when we have to do coding part in Parent directory controller. Please answer this.

Comment: according to https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html we have to implement business logic in plugin (theme).